# Creating a Tensor of Nth order, flatten a NxNxN tensor of 3rd order into a Matriz N^3x1, Sort the Matriz based on the third element of each vector

Tags: python, sorting, wolfram-mathematica, tensor, flatten

I've been trying to do something called eigenvalue reordering. In order to do that, I have to do something that in Wolfram Mathematica goes like:

```
lambdax[n_]:=n*Pi/2;

lambday[m_]:=m*Pi/2;

bii=(7 ((n^2 \[Pi]^2)/4 + 3/14 n \[Pi] Sin[(n \[Pi])/2] + 
   3/28 Sin[(n \[Pi])/2]^2 - 3/14 n \[Pi] Sin[(3 n \[Pi])/2] - 
   3/14 Sin[(n \[Pi])/2] Sin[(3 n \[Pi])/2] + 
   3/28 Sin[(3 n \[Pi])/2]^2 - 1/7 n \[Pi] Sin[2 n \[Pi]] + 
   1/28 Sin[2 n \[Pi]]^2))/(4 n^2 \[Pi]^2);

Reordbii=Flatten[Table[{n,m,(lambdax[n]^2+lambday[m]^2)/bii},{n,NN},{m,NN}],1];

Lambdabii = Sort[Reordbii, #1[[3]] < #2[[3]] &];

Lambdatakebii = Take[Lambdabii, NN];
```

The "Reordbii" command runs a two dimensional list and then flattens it into NN^2 vectors of dimension 1x3. The comand "Lambdabii" thens sort the NN^2 vectors based on the ascending order of the third element of each vector, that is, (lambdax[n]^2+lambday[m]^2)/bii. Then, the command "Lambdatakebii" takes the first NN vectors of "Lambdabii".
I am currently a begginer in Python, but i guess this simple algorith will run faster in it. However, i do not know how could I do it in Python. I wanted to rewrite the code in Python in order to run it on Colab. Does anyone knows how to help me here? Thanks!